How can i publish a Reactjs app to Azure using az cli?
I have a reactjs app . It sis react front end and c# mvc backend.  Now i am trying to publish this app to Azure.
The steps I have taken so far:
1.   I change to the directory where your solution file (`.sln`) is located. and run dotnet restore to restore NuGet packages for all projects

2. I then go to each project directory and run npm install

3. I then change to the directory of the client app and run the following
  
    npm install
    npm run build   

This is supposed to create a build directory , but i dont see any directory , it gets compiled into
C:\Dev\TestReactApp\TestReact.WebApp\TestReact.WebApp\bin\Debug\net7.0\

The client app is in
   C:\Dev\TestReactApp\TestReact.WebApp\TestReact.WebApp\ClientApp

Now once that has all completed I try to publish the app to a local drive first and then create a zip to deploy to Azure.
I publish as follows:

 dotnet publish  "C:\Dev\TestReactApp\TestReact.WebApp\TestReact.WebApp\TestReact.sln"  --  output    "c:\TestReactAppOutput\Test.zip"

Should i be publishing the .sln or should i be in the clientapp directory and run dotnet publish ?
Reason is if i make changes to the UI in code i dont see the changes of the ui after a publish to Azure
Then i create a zip file
$compress = @{
  Path = "c:\TestReactAppOutput\*"
  CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
 DestinationPath = "c:\testclientapp.zip"
}
Compress-Archive @compress

And then publish
  az login -u <uname> -p <pwd>
  az account set --subscription <subscription>
  $zipfile = "c:\testclientapp.zip"
  az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP> --name <APP_NAME> --    src $zipfile

After i publish if i look at the files in Azure it doesnt seem that the files have been pushed down correctly , because I cant navigate to the url of the site , it gives an error that it cant show the site , there are files missing ?
How can i do this process of building a .net core app , creating a zip and publishing to Azure using Powershell ?

To build a .NET core app and publish it to an Azure App service using PowerShell, use Publish-Azwebapp command or if you want to use the cloud shell, you can use az webapp deployment command as you have already used.
Refer Blog to deploy a react-app to azure app service.
Firstly, I have a created a sample .NET Core app with a React frontend in the Visual studio code terminal with the below npm commands.
npx create-react-app <AppName>
npm install

Note: Check the node version in the current terminal to avoid compatibility issues with the on-premises app service node version. Use npm update if required.
Once it is checked, run npm run build to execute the app as shown below. This will create a build folder once the app built successfully.


Now you have to publish .NET core app with the dotnet publish command from the solution folder directory path to create an output file.
After creating it, create the ZIP file using Compress-Archive as you already did.
Note: Make sure that you are verifying that the output directory contains the DLLs (backend) files and also the static files from the React app under the wwwroot directory before creating the zip file.

To publish, use:
 az webapp deployment source config-zip -g Jahnavi -n nodereactapp --src <sourcefilepath>



Also refer this blog for more related information.

The thing is , it doesnt compile into a build foilder. So can i change my appsettings.json file . At the moment to build i run npm run build from the clientapp directory , can i put an output folder ?

Also when i do dotnet publish , do i publish the .sln or the client app .csproj , project ?

I was looking for help with the exact steps involved

When you are doing the dotnet publish, you need to publish it on the .sln file. @Fiona

ok i will publish the solution file and check

so my steps above look correct ?
